# Azure Durable functions python DurableOrchestrationContext get_input returning null

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-durable-functions

I am testing this function, get_input() from Azure durable functions for Orchestra function. [More details of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions-durable/azure.durable_functions.durableorchestrationcontext?view=azure-python#get-input------typing-union-typing-any--nonetype-).

What I'm facing now is that, when I'm trying to test with postman and input a json input for e.g.

```
{
    "points": 222
}
```

as the json body and while calling for `http://localhost:<portnumber>/api/orchestrators/DurableFunctionsOrchestrator1`, it will always return me a null value when i try to return the get_input function's value

Below is a screenshot of what it returns me. As you can see everything is working fine since its completed status but the output always returns me a null.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a `Instance_id` you can pass your `Client_input` over there to get the `request body` parameter off the Durable Orchestration Client. Pass a ***Json*** serialized payload over the orchestrator.

```
async  def  main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:

client =  df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)

function_name =  req.route_params["functionName"]

requestBody =  json.loads(req.get_body().decode())

instance_id =  await  client.start_new(function_name, client_input=requestBody)
```

In a orchestrator, the code you can use the same `get_input()`:

```
requestBody : str  =  context.get_input()
```

I am tried with the [blog](https://www.welldocumentednerd.com/2021/04/06/passing-values-to-a-orchestrator-function-in-durable-functions/).  I am not getting any Null value on `get_input()`.